# how to set custom fonts on EditText with Appcompact Style accent color in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, typeface, android-typeface

I have create Custom `EditText` class with set `typeface` form `asset` folder .TTF file . That was set typeface on text, but my application style is `Appcompact` so that does not set bottom line as `accent color`.

Comment: Post your style xml.

Answer (score 0):

//here my Style/xml

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primary_text</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/secondary_text</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/MyAnimation.Window</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#c5c5c5</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

please use this code to set typeface

```
public static void setExternalFonts(EditText tv, Context cntx) {
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(cntx.getAssets(), "Ubuntu-Regular.ttf");
    tv.setTypeface(tf);
}
```

and pass Edittext and context.